# Predicting digit sequences in irrational numbers?

Tags: irrational-numbers

I'm trying to determine to what degree digits can be predicted in irrational numbers in general.

I learned about normal numbers via this prior question: [Predicting digits in $\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644464/predicting-digits-in-pi), which seems to imply that if numbers can be normal, digits may not be predictable.

If that's the case, is this an open question?

Comment: From Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#Properties_and_examples): ". . . the normal number theorem: almost all real numbers are normal, in the sense that the set of non-normal numbers has Lebesgue measure zero". As a consequence, if $x$ is randomly chosen from the interval $(0,1)$ (uniform distribution), then the probability that it is not normal is zero.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is randomly chosen from the uniform distribution on the interval $(0,1)$, the decimal digits of $x$ are independent, and equally likely to be $0,1,2,\ldots,9$.
In this sense, the digits of a random number are completely unpredictable.